# Where does Web API look in a Web Forms project for Controllers?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using Web API in my Web Forms project.  I have the following code in my project's `Application_Start` method in Global.asax:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("ApiDefault", "api/{controller}/{id}", New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional})
```

This is basically copied and pasted from a Microsoft tutorial on the subject.

I also have a test controller named `ValuesController`.  This class is just the default Web API controller one gets when creating a controller from the Add New Item wizard and is in a folder in my Web Forms site named `Controllers`:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web.Http

Public Class ValuesController
    Inherits ApiController

    ' GET api/<controller>
    Public Function GetValues() As IEnumerable(Of String)
        Return New String() {"value1", "value2"}
    End Function

    ' GET api/<controller>/5
    Public Function GetValue(ByVal id As Integer) As String
        Return "value"
    End Function

    ' POST api/<controller>
    Public Sub PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal value As String)

    End Sub

    ' PUT api/<controller>/5
    Public Sub PutValue(ByVal id As Integer, <FromBody()> ByVal value As String)

    End Sub

    ' DELETE api/<controller>/5
    Public Sub DeleteValue(ByVal id As Integer)

    End Sub

End Class
```

HOWEVER - when I go to `http://localhost/api/Values` - instead of seeing some XML serializing the strings `value1` and `value2`, I see an error message like so:

```
<Error>
    <Message>No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/api/Values'.</Message>
    <MessageDetail>No type was found that matches the controller named 'Values'.</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

So - clearly, routing is working, since instead of getting a 404 I get a message saying that the route itself doesn't resolve to anything.  But the route should resolve to something - specifically, my `ValuesController` class which is even in a folder named `Controllers`.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do your other routes work?

Comment: Yep, other routes appear to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  It's because apparently MVC requires that the Controllers folder be at the same level as the file declaring the routes - not (as I previously thought) simply at the root level.

Ugh.